# Is the set of nonnegative rational numbers under multiplication a minimal structure?

Tags: model-theory

I know that the set of nonnegative reals $\mathbb{R}^+$ under multiplication is a minimal structure. But what about the set of nonnegative rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}^+$ under multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not. For example, the set $X$ of nonnegative rationals which have square roots (in the nonnegative rationals) is infinite and co-infinite.

Incidentally, $X$ also gives a counterexample to o-minimality in the expansion $(\mathbb{Q}^+; \cdot, <)$.